# Extracting number from a cell of excel using R

Tags: r, mutation

These are my mutations details in a df(chr10:63661472 G>C,chr14:105246551 C>T, chr16:2225614 G>T)

I only want to extract the number of positions. I want such final file,
63661472
105246551
2225614

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: This is surely an easy task to do in R; however, you need to specify more clearly what your dataframe looks like. Can you post the data in reproducibel format in the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this.

Here's one with `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    extract(cells, into = "numbers", regex = ".*:(\\d+).*", remove = FALSE)
                cells   numbers
1  chr10:63661472 G>C  63661472
2 chr14:105246551 C>T 105246551
3   chr16:2225614 G>T   2225614
```

Here's one with `str_extract` and positive look-behind:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(numbers = str_extract(cells, "(?<=:)\\d+"))
```

Here's one with `sub` and backreference:

```
df %>%
  mutate(numbers = sub(".*:(\\d+).*", "\\1", cells))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  cells = c("chr10:63661472 G>C","chr14:105246551 C>T", "chr16:2225614 G>T")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the following piece of code:

```
numbers <- sub(".*:(\\d+).*", "\\1", df)
```